# ASP.NET MVC: How to add a library via the using command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to load generics within the aspx page. Here is my code

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>


<div id="CategorySelectBoxes">
<%  
    //this has syntax error
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    //get parentid list
    category c = new category();
```

is there a way to load the generic library?

Comment: Embedding code inside your .ascx page is code smell. It's not guaranteed to be bad, but you should consider refactoring. Your .ascx should only be a template. Push values into it in the code-behind.

Comment: Randolpho the Asp.Net MVC framework has no "code behind".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load it using the import directive either on the master page or for your view

```
<%@ Import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack%28VS.71%29.aspx) MSDN help topic.